# using sql to arrange a column with numbers and not letters

Tags: sql

How do I write an SQL statement to arrange this column

```
columnA
-------
10A
11C
12V
10D
8F
8R
9C
```

so that it returns a resultset in this order

```
columnA
-------
8F
8R
9C
10A
10D
11C
12V
```

(in numerical then alphabetical order)?

I have tried this statement:

```
Select columnA from tblStudents order by columnA
```

but it hasn't worked.

Comment: SQL-Server? MySQL? Postgres? Oracle? These functions are system dependend.

Comment: Kevin, accept the answers on your questions, don't leave them opened

Answer (score 4):

You would have to split the strings into the numerical part and the textual part, and convert the numerical part into an actual number.

I don't know which dialect of SQL you are using; this is for Microsoft SQL Server:

```
select columnA
from tblStudents
order by
  convert(int, substring(columnA, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%') - 1)),
  substring(columnA, patindex('%[^0-9]%'), 1000)
```

The `patindex('%[^0-9]%')` will find the first non-digit in the string, so the first `substring` gets the characters up that that point, and the second `substring` gets the characters from that point to the end of the string.